# Dependency injection/ORM in Vertx for Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, vert.x

I am learning vertx framework with Java, and I was wondering if there is any "**framework**" such as Spring Core to perform dependency injection or a library ?

And also, I was looking for an ORM to interact with a Relational Database (eg. Hibernate, Spring Data in Spring.

Thank you for you recommendation !

Comment: VertX is Java so using HIbernate/JPA should be perfectly fine.

Comment: Vert.x along with google guice as dependency injection and Ebean as ORM is perfect match, forget spring.

Comment: Note that Vert.X is a asynchronous reactive framework. Hibernate is backed by JDBC which is synchronous and blocking. Interoperating the two will likely kill off the benefits of Vert.X.

Comment: @OmidP Ebean still looks like it's JDBC-backed so still rubbish with a reactive framework.

Comment: Given all the mentions of Spring - why not abandon Vert.X and use Spring WebFlux?

Comment: when using spring webflux you will fall into handling transactions manually trap besides you can do blocking in vert.x which comes handy. anyway my experience from integrating spring,hibernate and vert.x is not good.

Comment: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/spring-examples/spring-example/README.adoc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an integration between Spring and Vert.x in your project:

You can see examples here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-vertx

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples

The general idea is to use Spring for configuring your application and use all its powerful annotations and dependency injection features and use Vert.x for for creating http server to handle your requests using Vert.x reactive model.

But if you find yourself writing all your code for handling requests inside an `executeBlocking` (for example, if you are using Spring Data and all your requests retrieve from DB) please don't do that. Instead try to find alternative asynchronous ways for doing things (for example, for DB you can use [Vert.x async clients](https://vertx.io/docs/#data_access)).